# Convert JSON response to Custom C# object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net, deserialization

I am making a call to a webservice and getting following Json Respons

```
{"handler":{"name":"abc"},"intent":{"name":"actions.intent.MAIN","params":{},"query":"Mit Google sprechen"},"scene":{"name":"actions.scene.START_CONVERSATION","slotFillingStatus":"UNSPECIFIED","slots":{},"next":{"name":"Start_Frage"}},"session":{"id":"ABwppHHVumDrliLJaLSikS6KnIlN7yYv6Z4XJCOYzEZt8Fr08RH6r0wtM2-E0v40lS2p1YosTDfpSCd5Lw","params":{},"typeOverrides":[],"languageCode":""},"user":{"locale":"de-DE","params":{},"accountLinkingStatus":"ACCOUNT_LINKING_STATUS_UNSPECIFIED","verificationStatus":"VERIFIED","packageEntitlements":[],"gaiamint":"","permissions":[],"lastSeenTime":"2021-04-01T10:06:59Z"},"home":{"params":{}},"device":{"capabilities":["SPEECH","RICH_RESPONSE","LONG_FORM_AUDIO"]}}
```

I used https://json2csharp.com/ to convert my Json String to C# Classes

```
 public class Handler
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Params
    {
    }

    public class Intent
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Params @params { get; set; }
        public string query { get; set; }
    }

    public class Slots
    {
    }

    public class Next
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Scene
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string slotFillingStatus { get; set; }
        public Slots slots { get; set; }
        public Next next { get; set; }
    }

    public class Session
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public Params @params { get; set; }
        public List<object> typeOverrides { get; set; }
        public string languageCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string locale { get; set; }
        public Params @params { get; set; }
        public string accountLinkingStatus { get; set; }
        public string verificationStatus { get; set; }
        public List<object> packageEntitlements { get; set; }
        public string gaiamint { get; set; }
        public List<object> permissions { get; set; }
        public DateTime lastSeenTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class Home
    {
        public Params @params { get; set; }
    }

    public class Device
    {
        public List<string> capabilities { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Handler handler { get; set; }
        public Intent intent { get; set; }
        public Scene scene { get; set; }
        public Session session { get; set; }
        public User user { get; set; }
        public Home home { get; set; }
        public Device device { get; set; }
    }
```

But how exactly do I parse my Json respone into an C# Object? Then make any changes to It and finally send a response back? Im a newbie in programming thats why a  Step by Step example would be very helpful

My current class looks like this. Variable body holds the Json response.

```
public class GoogleController : ControllerBase
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            var result = new Result();
            result.Value1 = 123;

            return Ok(result);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostWebHook()
        {

            string body;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
            {
                body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

            }
            return Ok("Test123");
                
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about using [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm)?

Comment: You don't have to explicitly deserialize the request content. If the action accepts an object that matches the JSON body, ASP.NET will deserialize it automatically

Comment: Perhaps it would be a good idea to run through some basic MVC tutorials. This is pretty fundamental to how it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `FromBody` attribute to deserialize body

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostWebHook([FromBody] Root root)
    {
        // root is deserialized body
        // modify root
        ...
        return Ok(root);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

https://json2csharp.com/ adds a command in the first line something like:

```
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
```

This line is used to deserialize the text.

Yours should be like:

```
var myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(body);
```

Comment: This is very manual and relies on JSON.Net being used. Instead, just let the framework do this for you, as the other answer shows.

Comment: @DavidG you are right arther's answer is better